# Split very large dataset into chunks and perform function

Tags: r, dplyr, split, group

I need to generate a lookup file with over 500,000,000 rows. The data I have is in this format:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Offset <- 25

Min1 <- -500000
Max1 <- 500000
Min2 <- -200000
Max2 <- 1400000

Num1 <- seq(Min1+Offset, Max1, 50)
Num2 <- seq(Min2+Offset, Max2, 50)

Data <- crossing(Num1,Num2)
```

I then need to run a function within mutate to generate a unique ID. So the output would have a structure like this:

```
Data_Mutate <- Data %>% 
    mutate(ID = 1:n())
```

However, my function cannot run on all the rows at once. So I need to chunk my dataset into 4,000,000 rows, add the mutate with my function and combine the outputs so they are in a single file that is structured like `Data_Mutate`. I think it's the size of my data, but when I try and split/group `Data` I get errors. I am sure I am missing an easier solution to my problem.

Comment: Not R, but the xsv cmd line utility can do this in one line of code.  https://gist.github.com/dannguyen/376c69380f99d1eeca7ad6e890f96259

Comment: if the dataset is already returning errors, surely even a dataframe with an index is going to lead to out of memory errors too?

Comment: Maybe make a data frame to keep track of the chunks, their sizes, and then assign ranges of IDs.  Then you can map through each chunk and compute them.  But as @Mark says, where are you going to put the output?